# three.js switch between Lambert and Phong

Tags: three.js

Is there a way to change the material type from Lambert to Phong (and reverse) just by changing the atttribute .type of the object.material and not reloading the whole object with new material ?

Comment: OK got it : make a new material where :map = previous material =>  var newmat= new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {  map: phongmesh.material.materials[i].map} ); and put this material to mesh.

Comment: Just remind that some attributes are lost when going from Phong to Lambert ... (e.g. bumpMap).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to lose attributes. If you're using [`THREE.BufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry), you can use groups instead.

**Groups**

```
var boxGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 10, 10);

// set up your groups
boxGeo.clearGroups();
boxGeo.addGroup(0, boxGeo.index.count, 0);
```

**Materials**

***Before THREE.js r85***

You'll be using `THREE.MultiMaterial`.

```
// add both of your materials to a multi-material
var mm = new THREE.MultiMaterial([
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: "red"}),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: "red"}),
]);

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeo, mm);
```

***For THREE.js r85 and beyond***

You can simply pass an array of materials to `THREE.Mesh`.

```
// add both of your materials to a multi-material
var mm = [
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: "red"}),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: "red"}),
];

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeo, mm);
```

**Swapping Materials**

And then when you want to swap material:

```
if(mesh.geometry.groups[0].materialIndex === 0){
    mesh.geometry.groups[0].materialIndex = 1;
}
else{
    mesh.geometry.groups[0].materialIndex = 0
}
```

Comment: OK ! than you for this clarification. This helps.